# How to call n no of USER profiles in test class

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help me out how to call  'n' no of USER profiles in test class.Any help very much appreciated.

Trigger :

```
trigger oli_multiple_products_before_insert on OpportunityLineItem (before insert) {

 Id userProfileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
  String userProfileName = [SELECT ID, Name from Profile Where Id = : userProfileId].Name;


  if( userProfileName != 'System Administrator' &&
      userProfileName !='Custom Marketing Users 10K 25K '&&
      userProfileName !='Customer Service User'&&
      userProfileName !='Fulfillment User'
     ) {


    for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert) {



            Integer line_Count = [SELECT COUNT()
                                    FROM OpportunityLineItem o
                                    WHERE o.OpportunityId = :oli.OpportunityId
                                    AND o.PriceBookEntryId = :oli.PriceBookEntryId  ];

            if (line_Count > 0) {
                oli.addError('A Product can not be added more than once to the Opportunity.');
         }                    
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Test class

```
 @isTest
    private class Oli_multiple_Products_TestClass{
    static testmethod void ValidateOlimultipleproducts(){
    Date closeDt = Date.Today();

//Find user with Profile = Sales and Service
        Profile SalesNService = [Select id from Profile where Name = 'Sales and Service' limit 1];
        User u = new User(
            Alias = 'standt', 
            Email='standarduser@testorg.com',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            LastName='Testing',
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_US',
            ProfileId = SalesNService.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName='standarduser@testorg.com'
        );


    Account acc = new Account (Name ='TestClassAccountOpportunitySegment', Region__c = 'AM', Persona__C = 'Artisan');
    //System.debug('AccountOpportunitySegment before insert of new Account: ' + acc.segment__C);
    insert acc;

    Opportunity opp = new opportunity (Name ='TestclassAccountOpportunitySegment', AccountId= acc.Id, StageName = 'Prospecting', 
                                       CloseDate = closeDt, ForecastCategoryName = 'Pipeline');
    insert opp;                                 

    OpportunityLineItem ooli = new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=opp.Id, TotalPrice=10, PriceBookEntryId='01ud0000004YWFqAAO');
    insert ooli;

    OpportunityLineItem ooli1 = new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=opp.Id, TotalPrice=10, PriceBookEntryId='01ud0000004YWFzAAO');
    insert ooli1;

    }
    }
```

Comment: So bulk testing?

Comment: @ EricSSH:In the trigger i do have users other than those users it should throw an error.so how do i use the users and the add error message in test class.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: If you wanted to test Error messages you need to use System.Asset and I believe it's getMessage(), you should be to find some documentation online

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you just want to select 'n' profiles?

```
List<Profile> profs = [select Id, Name from profile LIMIT n]
```

Or if you wanted to exclude the ones from your trigger it would look more like:

```
Set<String> bad = new Set<String>(){'System Administrator, Fulfillment User'};
//Didn't test that syntax, but you get the idea
List<Profile> profs = [select Id, Name from profile where name not in :bad LIMIT n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question could use some cleanup, but it seems you may be looking for the `System.runAs` method [[link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm)]. Create or query for a User with the profile that you desire, then pass the User record into `runAs`.

```
system.runAs(SYS_ADMIN)
{
    // do stuff
}
```